# Writing request in flash device

Tags: device, flash-memory

When writing to a flash device, what if the data size is less than the size of one page, how does OS deal with this writing request?

Comment: Note sure that I understand your question. Please keep in mind that: "For questions on Adobe's cross-platform multimedia runtime used to embed animations, video, and interactive applications into web pages. For questions related to memory, use the tag [flash-memory]."

Comment: Maybe fill the remaining with ZERO?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of flash.

- NAND flash has block oriented reads and writes with much larger erase-units
- NOR flash typically allows byte-wise reads and writes with much larger erase-units.

In both cases, the initial/erased state is `1` and a write pulls bits down to `0`.  Erasing returns them back to `1`.  Erases typically take much longer than writes.  Neither is terribly quick

If a `1` bit is written to the device during a write cycle, noting happens.  Thus it is possible with both types of device to perform a read-modify-write to achieve bit-level granularity.

In practice, most flash storage is used in a way that emulates magnetic rotating discs. These only support block-level reads and writes.  Operating system already use a number of strategies to deal with the wasted space this causes - one of which is to not bother and just simply waste it.

A problem with both types is that the erase-units are much bigger than blocks: thus it is necessary to empty an erase-unit of valid blocks before it can be erased.